# High Dimensional Array

Tags: r, arrays, loops, dimension

I have a 13 dimensional array:
MatrixQ<-array(0,dim=c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3))

How can I refer to ith dimension of it in a loop?

for (i in 1:13)
{
I want to assign the number i to the ith dimension of the array
} 
What command I should use?
Thanks,

Comment: You can do `MatrixQ[,,,,,,,,,,, i]`

Comment: MatrixQ<-array(0,dim=c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3))
for (i in 1:13)
{
  MatrixQ[,,,,,,,,,,,, i]
} like this? Didn't work. I want to assign value i to the ith dimension.

Comment: Not clear what you wanted.  Please show a small dimension example and your expected output

Comment: okay. Thanks. lets say I have 3 dimensional array. MatrixQ<-array(0,dim=c(2,2,2)), initially filled with zero. Desired output: MatrixQ[1,,] = 1, MatrixQ[2,,] = 1, MatrixQ[,1,] = 2, MatrixQ[,2,] = 2, MatrixQ[,,1] = 3, MatrixQ[,,2] = 3. Basically ith dimension of the array  = i. How can I do that in a loop?

Comment: I guess with your replacement, everything is changed to 3 (if you check `MatrixQ`) i.e. you are updating the the values already changed to 1, 2, etc. to 3.

Comment: Can you please check your assignment.

Comment: my bad. Sorry. I explain differently. Matrix<-array(0,dim=c(2,2,2)). Then I fill them in with 1s and 2s. Now, I want any of the two numbers in the ith dimension that is a 2, change it to 20. I just don't know how to refer to the ith dimension of an array in a loop. Thanks

Comment: Not clear about the expected output

Comment: Please see my responses below. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no easy way of doing this built into R. However, you can take advantage of the fact that an array is actually stored as a vector with a dimension (`dim`) attribute. You can therefore actually access elements directly without using multiple commas. The difficulty is working out which indices of the underlying vector represent the slice of the array you want. This just requires a bit of maths.

I think you're looking for something like this:

```r
at <- function(Array, Dimension, Slice, index = FALSE)
{
  if(!is.array(Array)) 
    stop("'at()' can only be called on arrays")

  if(!(is.numeric(Dimension) && Dimension > 0))
    stop("Invalid value of Dimension supplied to 'at()'")

  # Get the numbers of dimensions and elements in our Array
  n       <- length(Array)
  dims    <- dim(Array)
  n_dims  <- length(dims)

  if(Dimension > n_dims | Dimension < 1) 
    stop("Invalid dimension chosen in 'at()'")

  if(max(Slice) > dims[Dimension]) 
    stop("Invalid slice chosen for given dimension")

  final_result <- numeric()

  for(i in seq_along(Slice))
  {
    run_length  <- cumprod(c(1, dims)[-(n_dims + 1)])[Dimension]
    skip_length <- run_length * (dims[Dimension] - 1)

    # Now we simply make a repeating pattern of membership / non-membership
    pattern         <- rep_len(c(rep(T, run_length), rep(F, skip_length)), n)
    shifted_pattern <- c(rep(FALSE, run_length * (Slice[i] - 1)), pattern)
    loop_result     <- which(shifted_pattern[seq(n)])
    final_result    <- c(final_result, loop_result)
  }
  if(index == FALSE)
  {
    dims[Dimension] <- length(Slice)
    return(array(Array[final_result], dim = dims))
  }
  return(sort(final_result))
}
```

Here's how you can use it. Start with an array (let's have just 3 dimensions)

```
my_array <- array(0, dim = c(2, 3, 4))
my_array
#> , , 1
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0
#> 
#> , , 2
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0
#> 
#> , , 3
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0
#> 
#> , , 4
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0
```

Now I can get the indices of the underlying array that represent the 2nd matrix of the third dimension (i.e. `my_array[, , 2]`) like this:

```
at(my_array, 3, 2, index = T)
# [1]  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

That means if I write anything to `my_array[c(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)]`, it will change the elements in the appropriate slice of the matrix:

```
my_array[at(my_array, 3, 2, index = T)] <- 69
my_array
#> , , 1
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0
#> 
#> , , 2
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]   69   69   69
#> [2,]   69   69   69
#> 
#> , , 3
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0
#> 
#> , , 4
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0
```

And of course this means we can do a loop where we can select dimensions. Here, we'll first reset my_array to zeros, then we'll put the dimension number into each element in the first slice within that dimension. Notice that some cells get overwritten in the process if they belong to the first slice of multiple dimensions.

```r
# Reset my_array first
my_array[] <- 0

for(i in 1:3)
{
  my_array[at(my_array, i, 1, index = T)] <- i;
}
my_array
#> , , 1
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    3    3    3
#> [2,]    3    3    3
#> 
#> , , 2
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    2    1    1
#> [2,]    2    0    0
#> 
#> , , 3
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    2    1    1
#> [2,]    2    0    0
#> 
#> , , 4
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    2    1    1
#> [2,]    2    0    0
```

Although the example is for a 3-D array, this should work for any number of dimensions.

The reason for the `index = T` is that by omitting that, we can directly get the slice we want without using indexing:

```
at(my_array, 3, 1:2)
#> , , 1
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    3    3    3
#> [2,]    3    3    3
#> 
#> , , 2
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    2    1    1
#> [2,]    2    0    0
```

For the example in the OP's answer, you could use this to do as follows:

```
Indexlist2 <- numeric()

for(j in 2:4)
{
 if(StartPoint2QQQ[j] == 1)
 {
    j_matches <- which(at(MatrixQQQ, j, 1) == max(at(MatrixQQQ, j, 1)), arr.ind = T)
    Indexlist2 <- rbind(Indexlist2, j_matches)
  }
}
```

Now we have

```
Indexlist2
#>      dim1 dim2 dim3 dim4
#> [1,]    2    2    1    2
#> [2,]    2    2    2    1

MatrixQQQ[Indexlist2]
#> [1] 5.0 0.2
```

Comment: Thanks Allan, this is exactly what I was looking for. I was trying to avoid doing the math do change it from array to a vector order, but if that is the only way, I will work on it. And your 3D example clears it even more and will help me to write my own code. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it @movassat. If the answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as accepted so that other users with a similar problem can find their way to the answer more easily. Thanks

Comment: @movassat you shouldn't need to work on subsetting your own arrays - the function `at()` that I have showed you will work for any array of any number of dimensions.

Comment: @movassat so if you wanted the first slice of the thirteenth dimension in MatrixQ you would just do `MatrixQ[at(MatrixQ, 13, 1)]`

Comment: I just accepted it. Thanks. Oh Wow. I thought I need to modify that function. You made my life so easy on this! I really appreciate it.

Comment: two things. When I want to reproduce the code you wrote, I get this error: Error in rep(TRUE, consec[d]) : invalid 'times' argument. Second, in definition of the function you wrote: function(array = a, d = 1, slice = 1)
. Shouldn't it be function(array = a, d , slice)? Thanks

Comment: @movassat the function definition looks that way just to set default values. It's probably safer if you don't set default values, so I've just changed it in my answer to `at <- function(a, d, slice)`. As for the error you are getting, you can only select a single slice at a time. If you try to set multiple slices like `at(a, 10, 1:2)`, it will give this error. I will write an updated version that allows multiple slices.

Comment: Please see my own response below. I still get the error. I simplified the high dimensional problem to something easier to follow. I added the thing I need as a comment at the end of the code. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @movassat I have added error checking and the ability to add multiple indices. It should work now. Your loop in the example you have added in your own answer overwrites Indexlist2 each time. I take it you meant to append the result to Indexlist2? I'll add a working example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help and quick replies. Yes. In my example, it is overwriting. I need to change that. and I would appreciate seeing your working example too. Thanks

Comment: @movassat I have now changed the function to allow the actual matrix slice to be output. I have added an addendum to show how this can solve your problem.

Comment: I am facing some issues with the function. Please see my latest Answer to my own post. I just zero all the matrix and assign only one number (5000) to a specific element. When I want to find the index of the maximum element, and when I am using the "at' function, it gives the index wrong. dim 10 is supposed to be 2 not 1. I think it is either a bug or I am missing something. I appreciate your help. thanks.

Comment: If my previous comment was not clear: At the bottom of my own new answer I am showing the output. Because I only have one non-zero element, if I use which() command, it shows the rights element. But when I am using "at" function to look among the jth dimension only, the result I get is 1 at dim 10. Thanks

Comment: But that's the expected result @movassat. Remember you are taking a single _slice_ of the array at dimension 10, so anything in the tenth dimension can _only_ be at index 1 of that _slice_. Try to imagine it in 3 dimensions to make it easier. Suppose I have a 3 x 3 x 3 cubic box made of 27 smaller boxes, which are all white except a single red box in the middle of layer three. Its 3D co-ordinates will be [2, 2, 3]. Now suppose I take the top layer "slice" of the box. What are the co-ordinates of the red box in the _slice_? They are [2, 2, 1] since the 3rd dimension is only 1 box high.

Comment: understood. I was thinking it is giving the global index, not from the slice. To get the global index I just need to add: j_matches[j] <- j_matches [j]-1+j in the loop. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
at <- function(array = a, d = 1, slice = 1)
{
  consec <- cumprod(c(1, dim(a)))[-(length(dim(a)) + 1)]
  skip_n <- consec * (dim(a) - 1)
  basic_pattern <- rep_len(c(rep(TRUE, consec[d]), rep(FALSE, skip_n[d])), length(a))
  which(c(rep(FALSE, consec[d] * (slice - 1)), basic_pattern)[seq_along(a)])
}



StartPoint1QQQ <- array(c(1,1,0,0))
StartPoint2QQQ <- array(c(1,1,0,0))+1
MatrixQQQ<-array(0,dim=c(2,2,2,2))
MatrixQQQ[2,2,1,1] <- 0.1
MatrixQQQ[2,2,2,1] <- 0.2
MatrixQQQ[2,2,1,2] <- 5
for(j in 2:4)
{

  if(StartPoint2QQQ[j] == 1)
 {

    Indexlist2 <- which( MatrixQQQ[at(MatrixQQQ, j, 1)] == max( MatrixQQQ[at(MatrixQQQ, j, 1)]), arr.ind = TRUE)
  }
}
#I simplified my higher dimension problem. MatrixQQQ is my 4 dimensional matrix that stores 
#scores for each state (there are 4 states). Here the first state is time, and 2nd-4th states are cost.
#I care for cost only for now, so states 2:4 are of interest. I want to get a list of indices 
# in which the slice is 1 and among them find the ones with maximum MatrixQQQ value

#The expected value here is 2,2,1,2 because its MatrixQQQ value is the highest, 5.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
at <- function(Array, Dimension, Slice, index = FALSE)
{
  if(!is.array(Array)) 
    stop("'at()' can only be called on arrays")

  if(!(is.numeric(Dimension) && Dimension > 0))
    stop("Invalid value of Dimension supplied to 'at()'")

  # Get the numbers of dimensions and elements in our Array
  n       <- length(Array)
  dims    <- dim(Array)
  n_dims  <- length(dims)

  if(Dimension > n_dims | Dimension < 1) 
    stop("Invalid dimension chosen in 'at()'")

  if(max(Slice) > dims[Dimension]) 
    stop("Invalid slice chosen for given dimension")

  final_result <- numeric()

  for(i in seq_along(Slice))
  {
    run_length  <- cumprod(c(1, dims)[-(n_dims + 1)])[Dimension]
    skip_length <- run_length * (dims[Dimension] - 1)

    # Now we simply make a repeating pattern of membership / non-membership
    pattern         <- rep_len(c(rep(T, run_length), rep(F, skip_length)), n)
    shifted_pattern <- c(rep(FALSE, run_length * (Slice[i] - 1)), pattern)
    loop_result     <- which(shifted_pattern[seq(n)])
    final_result    <- c(final_result, loop_result)
  }
   if(index == FALSE)
  {
    dims[Dimension] <- length(Slice)
    return(array(Array[final_result], dim = dims))
  }
  return(sort(final_result))
}


IMAX <- 2

MatrixQ<-array(0,dim=c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3))
MatrixQ[2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,IMAX] <- 5000

j <- 10


which(MatrixQ == max(MatrixQ), arr.ind = T)

which(at(MatrixQ, j, 2) == max(at(MatrixQ, j, 2)), arr.ind = T)



######ANSWER I GET:###########################
####which(MatrixQ == max(MatrixQ), arr.ind = T)
####      dim1 dim2 dim3 dim4 dim5 dim6 dim7 dim8 dim9 dim10 dim11 dim12 dim13
####[1,]    2    2    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     2     1     2     2

####> which(at(MatrixQ, j, 2) == max(at(MatrixQ, j, 2)), arr.ind = T)
####       dim1 dim2 dim3 dim4 dim5 dim6 dim7 dim8 dim9 dim10 dim11 dim12 dim13
####[1,]    2    2    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     2     2
```